# Having problems with assigning variable to each other

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to swap the values of some variables in my code below:

```
def MutationPop(LocalBestInd,clmns,VNSdata):

    import random

    MutPop = []
    for i in range(0,VNSdata[1]):

        tmpMutPop = LocalBestInd

        #generation of random numbers
        RandomNums = []
        while len(RandomNums) < 2:
            r = random.randint(0,clmns-1)
            if r not in RandomNums:
                RandomNums.append(r)
        RandomNums = sorted(RandomNums)

        #apply swap to berths
        tmpMutPop[0][RandomNums[0]] = LocalBestInd[0][RandomNums[1]]
        tmpMutPop[0][RandomNums[1]] = LocalBestInd[0][RandomNums[0]]

        #generation of random numbers
        RandomNums = []
        while len(RandomNums) < 2:
            r = random.randint(0,clmns-1)
            if r not in RandomNums:
                RandomNums.append(r)
        RandomNums = sorted(RandomNums)

        #apply swap to vessels

        tmpMutPop[1][RandomNums[0]] = LocalBestInd[1][RandomNums[1]]
        tmpMutPop[1][RandomNums[1]] = LocalBestInd[1][RandomNums[0]]

        MutPop.append(tmpMutPop)

    Neighborhood = MutPop
    return(Neighborhood)
```

my problem is that I do not want to change the variable "`LocalBestInd`" and want to use it as a reference to generate new "tmpMutPop"s in the loop, but the code put "`LocalBestInd`" equal to "`tmpMutPop`" every time that loop is iterated. The same problem happens for other assignments (e.g., `tmpMutPop[1][RandomNums[1]] = LocalBestInd[1][RandomNums[0]]`) in this code.

Would you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you

Masoud

Comment: You specifically made `LocalBestInd` and `tmpMutPop` refer to the same list structure.  First, you need `tmpMutPop = copy.deepcopy(LocalBestInd)`.  That should get you moving.  Before you post again, please repeat the intro tour, especially expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This posting needs a lot of sculpting to make a viable Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import copy
```

And change the line

```py
tmpMutPop = LocalBestInd
```

to this:

```py
tmpMutPop = copy.copy(LocalBestInd)
```

Depending on the structure of `LocalBestInd`, you may need `copy.deepcopy()` instead.

Here's a quote from the [copy documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html) that explains what's going on:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

Comment: It worked perfectly.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `LocalBestInd` is a list, the problem, I think, is that when you're setting

`tmpMutPop = LocalBestInd`

in the loop, the value `tmpMutPop` is not a separate list but is just a reference to the list `LocalBestInd`, which actually contains the data. There's only one list - when you try to update the former, you're really only updating the latter.

Simple example of this works here:

```
>>> x = [1, 2]; y = x; y[0] = 2; print(x)
[2, 2]
```

What may help you here is calling `.copy()` on your list, e.g.:

```
>>> x = [1, 2]; y = x.copy(); y[0] = 2; print(x)
[1, 2]
```

If that doesn't work then check out the other list copying methods in this SO answer: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)